# The application "my_electron_app" cannot be opened on macos

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

I developed an application using electron platform. I created a DeveloperID certificate by issuing CSR. I used electron-builder to build, sign and notarize my application.
I verified the signature using the command `codesign -dv --verbose=4 /Path/To/Application.app` and verified the certificate using the command `spctl -a -v --type install /Path/To/Application.app`

the first command output is:

```
Executable=/Users/werad-03/Documents/my_electron_app/my_electron_app_v2_POM_with_TATA/TATA-desktop/dist/mac/my_electron_app.app/Contents/MacOS/my_electron_app
Identifier=my_electron_app02
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20500 size=1817 flags=0x10000(runtime) hashes=46+7 location=embedded
VersionPlatform=1
VersionMin=657920
VersionSDK=659200
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=3e8e0f0d21d972f3466edee7c1f75acc1dc2ddb2
CandidateCDHashFull sha1=3e8e0f0d21d972f3466edee7c1f75acc1dc2ddb2
CandidateCDHash sha256=c6c6c4bcda74e158e023736305bafa34be3369b2
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=c6c6c4bcda74e158e023736305bafa34be3369b2fe7928bc9e530de342dd5101
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CMSDigest=35493b34272c1732f1bc8e9d1d7aba27bd0599c01448f0a6d6ecf53ff9e5cd14
CMSDigestType=2
Executable Segment base=0
Executable Segment limit=167936
Executable Segment flags=0x1
Page size=4096
Launch Constraints:
  None
CDHash=c6c6c4bcda74e158e023736305bafa34be3369b2
Signature size=9123
Authority=Developer ID Application: DIGITAL SOLUTIONS - FZCO (95C3U6CXH8)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=21. Sep 2023 at 02:49:16
Info.plist entries=29
TeamIdentifier=85C3U6CXH7
Runtime Version=10.15.0
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=105
Internal requirements count=1 size=176
```

and the output of the second command is:

```
my_electron_app.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
```

my .plist file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
        <true/>
        <key> com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.device.screen-capture</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.private.accessibility.app-audit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires automation permissions to interact with other applications for reading mouse clicks and keystrokes.</string>
        <key>NSScreenCaptureUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires screen capture permissions to record the screen.</string>
        <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires microphone usage permissions to enable voice calls.</string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires camera usage permissions to enable video calls.</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

but when I run the application I get the following error:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 72A47E48-846F-4EFB-A47E-DE06AE872D51
CrashReporter Key:   61141667-4FFF-8213-8B3A-0C9970B0E1A6
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             my_electron_app [653]
Path:                /Applications/my_electron_app.app/Contents/MacOS/my_electron_app
Identifier:          my_electron_app02
Version:             2.0.1 (2.0.1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           my_electron_app02 [782]

Date/Time:           2023-09-21 23:17:35.0485 +0300
Launch Time:         2023-09-21 23:17:34.9190 +0300
OS Version:          macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1 Taskgated Invalid Signature

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0                                       0x7ff7ffe2f8bc 0x7ff7ffe2c000 + 14524


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000000  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x0000000000000000   lr: 0x0000000000000000
    sp: 0x0000000305bb9bd0   pc: 0x00007ff7ffe2f8bc cpsr: 0x00001000
   far: 0x0000000000000000  esr: 0x00000000  Address size fault

Binary Images:
    0x7ff7ffe2c000 -     0x7ff7ffe5bfff  (*) <6f797d84-b330-3656-9a0d-7b3dbd3f8a07> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF
```

could you please help with that, thankyou

1.I tried to delete the app from Applications folder and reinstall it from the dmg file.
2.I tried to disable Gatekeeper on my device.
3.I tried to re-sign and re-notarize the app.

but non of the mentioned solution was successful.